# Disable AWS Api Gateway http --> https 307 redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, redirect, aws-api-gateway

By default, Api Gateway reponds with a 307 redirect to any unsecure http request. I'm fine with http being disallowed, but my security concern is that http libraries will transparently follow the redirect and developers would not even notice that they sent their sensitive header values (an api token) unsecured.
Rather than a redirect, I'd rather Api Gateway responded with a 403 Forbidden or something like that, so developers know they should stop sending their tokens over http. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For API side : connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

OR

Checkout this AWS DOC : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html

If you send POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, or PATCH **over HTTP** with an HTTP to HTTPS cache behavior and a request protocol version of **HTTP 1.1 or above**, CloudFront redirects the request to a HTTPS location with a **HTTP status code 307 (Temporary Redirect)**. This guarantees that the request is sent again to the new location using the same method and body payload.

If you send POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, or PATCH requests over HTTP to HTTPS cache behavior with a request protocol **version below HTTP 1.1**, CloudFront returns a **HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden)**.